# Hide and Show a div when a tab is active ( selected )

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, show-hide

I have this tabs built.

When I click on Round Trip, I want to make disappear that Flight 2 form.

But since that is needed on multi-city, I want it to show back on

multi-city.

[image]

I used this

```
jQuery('#rdbOneWay').attr("class","onewaybuttonchecked");
jQuery('#rdbRoundTrip').attr("class","roundwaybuttonchecked");  
jQuery('#rdbMultiCity').attr("class","multiwaybuttonchecked");  

jQuery('.ret_date_block').attr("id","noreturndate");    


   $("#noreturndate").hide();
$(".onewaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
    $("#noreturndate").hide();
});

      $(".roundwaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
    $("#noreturndate").show();
});

          $(".multiwaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
    $("#noreturndate").show();
});

});
```

I used this to hide something on the One Way tab.
If:

```
$(".roundwaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
    $("#noreturndate").show();
});
```

If I use here the correct id of Flights 2 to hide it on the Round-Trip, it does its job but when I switch between One-Way and Round-Trip it shows nothing. 
This line get's in action when I go from Multi City to Round-Trip.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.

I used same code as above

```
jQuery('#rdbOneWay').attr("class","onewaybuttonchecked");
jQuery('#rdbRoundTrip').attr("class","roundwaybuttonchecked");  
jQuery('#rdbMultiCity').attr("class","multiwaybuttonchecked");  

jQuery('.pnlFlight2').attr("id","pnlFlight2");  


   $("#pnlFlight2").hide();
$(".onewaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
    $("#pnlFlight2").hide();
});

      $(".roundwaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
    $("#pnlFlight2").hide();
});

          $(".multiwaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
    $("#pnlFlight2").show();
});
```

and it did the trick, I don't know why it didn't work earlier but glad it did now.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a conditional in here.

In your JQuery function, try something like this:

```
function radioButton() {
if (document.getElementById('htmlElement1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('htmlElement2').style.visibility = 'visible';
} else {
    document.getElementById('htmlElement').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Please note that since I cannot view your HTML - I am not sure what elements you are using so where i say `htmlElement 1 (or 2)` please fill that in with the appropriate elements.

Let me know you results!

Comment: here is the link : http://www.airlineticketcentre.ca, i tried it but it didn't work @jkimbrough

Comment: Try tweaking your code like this:  $(".roundwaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
    $("#noreturndate").hide();
});

Comment: I did but when i switch from One Way to Round, it will show me the same layout as One Way. After i switch to Multi-City, then the code fires and it does it's thing.
$(".roundwaybuttonchecked").on("click", function(){
$("#pnlFlight2").show();
 });

Comment: Your problem is the setup of "One way".  when looking at your application - One way is currently setup as Round trip...why do you need a returning flight for One Way?

Comment: I don't, I fixed it with the above jQuery. I wanted to use the same logic as on One-Way for the Round Trip but it doesn't work.